# Ionic 3 images not displaying on device

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I'm developing an Ionic 3 application. it has some custom styling done, and some images are instantiated via scss as backgrounds.
Thing is, when I run it on local (ionic serve) it works just fine.
But when I build an apk and run it on my phone, images are gone.

I've debugged it, and turns that image files are there, but there's no image on them.

Here's a piece of scss:

```
&:nth-child(3) {
        border-right:none;
        padding-top: 28px;
        background: url('../../../assets/imgs/tabs/more-tab.png') no-repeat center 4px;
        background-size: 20px 20px;
      }
```

When I inspect the app from chrome, I can see the image file on sources tab. But there's no preview for it.

I have been researching a bit, and  found only relative/absolute path workarounds (Which none worked). Actually, if I change the image path, it's not even loaded inside the apk.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

I leverage a background image in the app.scss and below works for me on web/ios/android.  I think the relative paths are supposed to be in relation to the the output structure of `www/build` (not the code directory structure).  So maybe try with just 1 `../`

`background: url("../assets/img/truck.png") no-repeat;`

Comment: That was precisely it!

Answer (score 1):

So, turns thatin order to load images both with ionic serve and on a build, image path has to be like this:

```
../assets/path-to-image
```

Hope this helps someone else